# Jmeter while condition - adding multiple condition is not working as expected

Tags: while-loop, jmeter

Iam in a situation that i need to check 4 conditions in a loop, as soon as condition matches loop will exit, if not matched then i need to run for <=9 attempts.  below is the condition i have used.
below condition is working fine in case if 4 condition results are matched, in case if any one condtion is failed jmeter is running in a infinite loop.

```
${jexl3("${compilerstatus}" != "Compilation Successful." && "${compilerstatus2}" != "Compilation Successful." && "${compilerstatus3}" != "Compilation Successful." && "${compilerstatus4}" != "Compilation Successful.")} || ${jexl3("${counter_value}" <= "9")}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your problem is that the loop doesn't break after 9th iteration it's due to comparing 2 [Strings](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) using `<=` operator, you should remove quotation marks so it would be [Integers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html).

I think you need to change this line:

```
|| ${jexl3("${counter_value}" <= "9")
```

to this one:

```
|| ${counter_value} <= 9)
```

Something like:

```
${__jexl3("${compilerstatus}" != "Compilation Successful." && "${compilerstatus2}" != "Compilation Successful." && "${compilerstatus3}" != "Compilation Successful." && "${compilerstatus4}" != "Compilation Successful." && ${__jm__While Controller__idx} <= 9,)}
```

More information:

- [Java Expression Language (JEXL)](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-jexl/)
- [Using the While Controller in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/while-controller-jmeter)